# reading a line from ifstream into a string variable

Tags: c++, string, ifstream, getline

In the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string x = "This is C++.";
    ofstream of("d:/tester.txt");
    of << x;
    of.close();


    ifstream read("d:/tester.txt");
    read >> x;
    cout << x << endl ;
}
```

### `Output :`

`This`

Since >> operator reads upto the first whitespace i get this output. How can i extract the line back into the string ?

I know this form of `istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );`  **but i want to store it in a string variable.**
How can i do this ?

Comment: See also the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116951/using-fstream-to-read-every-character-including-spaces-and-newline

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Use the [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) from `<string>`.

```
 istream & getline(istream & is,std::string& str)
```

So, for your case it would be:

```
std::getline(read,x);
```

Comment: The return value of `getline()` (a stream object) should be evaluated in a bool expression. Bool evaluation of the stream object does a very important trick here: it evaluates `failbit` and `badbit` of the underlying stream. One should make use of that. A more in-depth explanation can be found here: http://gehrcke.de/2011/06/reading-files-in-c-using-ifstream-dealing-correctly-with-badbit-failbit-eofbit-and-perror