# C++ ifstream string

Tags: c++, string, fstream, ifstream

In a file I have pair of names on each line. Like this:

John Dave

Antoine Gerda

Sara Math

and so on...

What I want to do is to output that pair into one string. Like this:

```
string pairs[100];
ifstream inFile("duom.txt");
int n; //how many pairs

inFile >> n;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    inFile >> pairs[i];
}
```

This doesn't work because it reacts on the space.

```
getline(inFile,pairs[i]);
```

isn't acceptable as it skips a code after.

So my question is: would be there a possibility to read those 2 names into one string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [reading a line from ifstream into a string variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663131/reading-a-line-from-ifstream-into-a-string-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem isn't getline, which is fine for your task, but the indexing. You should start from 0

```
for(int i=0;i < n;i++){
    getline(inFile, pairs[i]);
}
```

**edit**: as Kerrek SB noted, there could be a bug. after `inFile >> n` we should skip the newline: adding a dummy `getline(inFile, pairs[0]);` can get rid of it.

Comment: You have to be careful when mixing `getline` and `>>`, though.