# How to read string from file with line break using ifstream c++?

Tags: c++, line, ifstream

I used this code to read lines from file, but I noticed, that it didn't read line breaks:

```
ifstream fs8(sourceFile);
string line;

while (getline(fs8, line))
{
   //here I am doing convertation from utf8 to utf16, but I need also to convert symbol "\n"
}
```

How to read line with line breaks ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reading a line from ifstream into a string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663131/reading-a-line-from-ifstream-into-a-string-variable)

Answer (score 0):

[`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) reads data up to a delimiter, which is not stored. By default, that delimiter is `'\n'`. So you would have to either:

a) Pick a different delimiter -- but then you would no longer read "lines".

b) Add the newline to the data read (`line += '\n'`).

I'd go for b), if you really *need* that newline converted. (I don't quite see why that would be necessary, but who am I to judge. ;-) )

Comment: but maybe there is some other function, which automatically read line with delimeter ?

Comment: @VFbvb: Not to my knowledge, not for C++ style iostreams. As adding the newline / delimiter manually is generally easier (and less often desired) than removing it, I don't see why there *should* be, anyway. C style `fgets()` stores the newline, but I don't think it's worth the hassle of handling `char` arrays and checking for incomplete reads. Add the newline yourself and be done with it.